# Are 3 collinear vectors also coplanar?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've read something about how collinear vectors don't "establish a plane", but as far as I'm concerned they would still exist along one single plane when their directions are all the same. Or does collinearity not mean existing along the same line? Or does existing along the same line somehow not imply existing on the same plane?

Comment: It's not that they don't lie in a common plane, it's that they lie in infinitely many planes (in $3$ space or higher). If the vectors are noncollinear, then they establish a *unique* plane.

Comment: They are coplanar, but they do not determine a plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the following arbitrary case in $\mathbb R^3$:

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you! Very good answer, I feel these questions are much easier to understand with illustrations.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is the same as whether a line determines a plane (here, the line is the span of the collinear vectors). Yes, a line does lie on a plane, but it also lies on infinitely many planes. For visualization, consider turning the pages of a book, where the pages are planes and the spine of the book is a line: no matter how you angle the page (plane), the spine (line) lies on it.

Answer (score 1):

There have to be three non-collinear points to uniquely determine a plane..

If the three points lie on the same line( i.e there are 3 collinear vectors), then there will be many planes that will contain them( i.e contain those 3 points). (These planes will resemble pages of a book in which the collinear points are binding from the middle).Here is an illustration -:[image]